# How can I publish a word document on the same URL but changing content from time to time?

Tags: google-drive, dropbox, sharing, hosting, bit.ly

I have a very simple thing to do which suddenly became hugely difficult. I need to publish a word document on the same URL but I will change its content from time to time.

Solutions I tried so far:

dropbox: link changes once document is updated

google drive: after some modest number of downloads (I believe <100 a day) kept saying

Too many users have viewed or downloaded this file recently. Please try accessing the file again later. If the file that you are trying to access is particularly large or is shared with many people, it may take up to 24 hours to be able to view or download the file. If you still can't access a file after 24 hours, contact your domain administrator.

I also attempted to de-volatile urls with bit.ly which appears to be unable to reuse links either!

Can anyone suggest a free and reliable solution?

Comment: I believe this question already has an answer somewhere else on [webapps.se], but I can't find it. If anyone can find the original, please mark this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

A filing cabinet on Google Sites may work.

(Disclaimer:  I haven't tested it, don't know it's subject to teh same issue that Drive apparently has - but I know that if you simply upload a new file with the same name, the URL is the same.)

Comment: How exactly a filling cabinet will help here?

Comment: A filing cabinet is a type of "page" in Google Sites.   You make it, and put your file into it - and then you can get a URL for the file which can be used elsewhere.

Comment: It tends to get tired the same way as Google Drive. Any Google-free alternative?